# HTMX hx-target moves content down instead of replacing it in designated id

Tags: python-3.x, django, htmx

I am having the problem where my hx-target doesn't seem to be replacing the content where the target I point to.  I'm using a a base html file that has a div with an id of requestcontent in it.  All of my links, form actions and hx actions that I'm using point to this div for replacement.

My initial access from an item on the menu sidebar works fine and gives results as shown here:
[image]

Even when I click on the "Add bill" button the page renders correctly:

[image]

However if I press close or save on this page when I return to the original page the top of the add page is still present:

[image]

This is true from both my add and delete pages.

[image]

[image]

The initial page that starts out the entire process is in billlist.html

```
<div class="container shadow min-vh-100 py-2">
 
    {% include 'acctsite/partials/messages.html' %}
 
    <h2>Accounts Payable / Bills Listing</h2>

    <div class="row" align="right">
        <div class="col-10"></div>
        <div class="col-2 pb-1">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
                    hx-trigger="click" hx-get="{% url 'expadd' %}" hx-target="#requestcontent">
                    Add bill
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col h5">Date</div>
        <div class="col h5">Vendor</div>
        <div class="col h5">Description</div>
        <div class="col h5">Amount</div> 
        <div class="col h5">Paid Info</div>
        <div class="col-1"></div>
        <div class="col-1"></div>
        <div class="col-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <hr>
    </div>
    {% for bill in  bills %}
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col">
                {{bill.date}}
                {% if  bill.due_date is not None %}
                    <br>{{ bill.due_date }}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="col">{{bill.vendor.name}}</div>
            <div class="col">{{bill.description}}</div>
            <div class="col" align="right">${{bill.amount|floatformat:2}}</div>
            <div class="col">
                {% if bill.paid_date is not None %}
                    {{ bill.paid_date }} <br>
                    {{ bill.check_number}}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" hx-trigger="click">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                {% if bill.paid_date is None %}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" hx-trigger="click" >Pay</button>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" hx-trigger="click" hx-get="{% url 'expdel' bill.transactionID %}" hx-target="#requestcontent" >Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <hr>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The add and delete page are very similar in the way they are written.  Add uses a form to gather the information to perform the add:

**expadd.html**

```
<div class="container shadow min-vh-100 py-2">
    {% include 'acctsite/partials/messages.html' %}
    <h2>Add Expense/Bill</h2>
        <form hx-post="{% url 'expadd' %}" hx-targe="#requestcontent" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %} 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <strong>Vendor</strong>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-5">
                    <select class="form-control" name="vendor">
                        {% for vendor in vendors %}
                            <option value="{{vendor.id}}">{{vendor.name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}    
                    </select> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <strong>Date</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="date">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <strong>Due Date</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <input class="form-control" type="date" name="duedate">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <strong>Description</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <strong>Amount</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <input class="form-control" type="number"  step=".01" name="amount">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-5">
                </div>

                <div class="col-1">
                    <input class="form-control btn btn-secondary" type="submit" name="action"  value="Close">
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">    
                    <input class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name="action"  value="Save">
                </div>               

            </div>
        </form>    
 
</div>
```

**expdel.html**

```
<div class="container shadow min-vh-100 py-2">
    {% include 'acctsite/partials/messages.html' %}
    <h2>Confirm Expense Delete</h2>
        <form hx-post="{% url 'expdel' %}" hx-targe="#requestcontent" hx-swap="outerHTML" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %} 
            <input type="hidden" name="tranID" value="{{ bill.transactionID}}">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <strong>Vendor</strong>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-5">
                    {{ bill.vendor.name }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <strong>Date</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    {{ bill.date }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <strong>Due Date</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    {{ bill.due_date }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <strong>Description</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    {{ bill.description }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <strong>Amount</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    ${{ bill.amount | floatformat:2 }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-5">
                </div>

                <div class="col-1">
                    <input class="form-control btn btn-secondary" type="submit" name="action"  value="Close">
                </div>
                <div class="col-1">    
                    <input class="form-control btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name="action"  value="Delete">
                </div>               

            </div>
        </form>    
 
</div>
```

The base template contains the definition of the page that contains the div id=requestcontent.

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
{% load humanize %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}RJD Crew Accounting{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <style>
      .hoverDiv {background: #fff;}
      .hoverDiv:hover {background: #f5f5f5;}
    </style>
    {% block head %}
    {% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body class="bg-light">
    
    <nav class="navbar  navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-expand-lg  ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-primary text-white">
            <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="{% url 'home' %}"><img src="{% static 'rjdcrew-logo.png' %}" height="50"  ><br>Accounting</a>
          </div>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item" >
                <a class="nav-link  {% if '/' == request.get_full_path %}active{% endif %}"  href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Expenses
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item {% if 'expenses' in request.get_full_path %}active{% endif %}" href="{% url 'expenses'%}">Reimbursements</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bills</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{%url 'logout' %}">logout</a>
                </li>
              {% else %}  
                <li class="nav-item">Register</li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{%url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                </li>
              {% endif %}  

            </ul>

          </div>
        </div> 
      </nav>
      <div class="container p-10">
      {% for message in messages %}
 
        <div class="alert {{ message.tags }}  alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
          {{ message }}
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>

      {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid overflow-hidden">
        <div class="row vh-100 overflow-auto">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-light d-flex sticky-top">
                <div class="d-flex flex-sm-column flex-row flex-grow-1 align-items-center align-items-sm-start px-3 pt-2 text-white">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-sm-column flex-row flex-nowrap flex-shrink-1 flex-sm-grow-0 flex-grow-1 mb-sm-auto mb-0 justify-content-center align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="nav-link px-sm-0 px-2">
                                <i class="fs-5 bi-house"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{% url 'reports' %}" class="nav-link  px-sm-0 px-2">
                                <i class="fs-5 bi-speedometer2"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Dashboard</span> </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle px-sm-0 px-2" id="dropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fs-5 bi-credit-card"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Expense Reimburse</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" hx-get="{% url 'approve' %}" hx-target="#requestcontent">Approve</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" hx-get="{% url 'pay' %}" hx-target="#requestcontent">Pay</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" hx-get="{% url 'explist' %}" hx-target="#requestcontent">List</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                                </li>
                                
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li >
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link px-sm-0 px-2" hx-get="{% url 'billlist' %}" hx-target="#requestcontent" hx-swap="outerHTML" >
                                <i class="fs-5 bi-receipt"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Expense Bills</span>
                            </a>                       
                        </li>
                        <li >
                          <a  href="#" class="nav-link px-sm-0 px-2"  hx-get="{% url 'payments' %}" hx-target="#requestcontent" >
                              <i class="fs-5 bi-journal-minus"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Payments</span>
                          </a>
                      
                        </li>  
                        <li >
                          <a  href="#" class="nav-link px-sm-0 px-2"   hx-get="{% url 'journal' %}" hx-target="#requestcontent" >
                              <i class="fs-5 bi-currency-dollar"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Journal</span>
                          </a>
                      
                        </li> 
                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle px-sm-0 px-2" id="dropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                              <i class="fs-5 bi-printer"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Reports</span>
                          </a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdown">
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" hx-get="{% url 'checkreg' %}" hx-target="#requestcontent">Check Register</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" hx-get="{% url 'journalrep'  %}" hx-target="#requestcontent">Journal</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" hx-get="{% url 'accountrep' %}" hx-target="#requestcontent">Accounts</a></li>
                              
                          </ul>
                      </li>                        
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link px-sm-0 px-2">
                                <i class="fs-5 bi-people"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Users</span> </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle px-sm-0 px-2" id="dropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                              <i class="fs-5 bi-gear"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Settings</span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdown">
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" hx-get="{% url 'adduser' %}" hx-target="#requestcontent">Add User</a></li>
                              <li><a class="dropdown-item" hx-get="{% url 'addvendor'  %}" hx-target="#requestcontent">Add Vendor</a></li>
                          </ul>                              
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="{%url 'logout' %}" class="nav-link px-sm-0 px-2"><i class="fs-5 bi-sign-stop"></i><span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Sign out</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex flex-column h-100">
                <main class="row">
                    <div class="col pt-4" id="requestcontent">
                      {% block content %} 
                        Content goes here
                      {% endblock %}               
                    </div>
                </main>
                <footer class="row bg-light py-4 mt-auto">
                    <div class="col"> Copyright 2022 Skyout Services</div>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.8.2" integrity="sha384-+8ISc/waZcRdXCLxVgbsLzay31nCdyZXQxnsUy++HJzJliTzxKWr0m1cIEMyUzQu" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{% static "dialog.js" %}"></script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There seems to be missplelling - `hx-targe=`. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes that was part of the problem.  The other part was I had added some hx-swap to replace the outer HTML tag which then removed my target.